# Actual word for "Caringness"?

Tags: word-request

> *This is just one of many examples where she demonstrates incredible work ethic, dedication and caringness.*

I'd like  to find an actual english word that conveys the meaning of the made-up word "caringness". Can you please suggest a few options?

Comment: It might help if you write a sentence or two with the made up word in the context you are thinking of.

Comment: "Doting" might be appropriate, but it wouldn't work in certain sentence constructions.

Comment: Can you describe how you'd like to use the word?

Comment: Please edit your question, and explain more about the "flavor" of caring you are talking about. People are starting to guess, in part because there are many ways to show caring: an employee can care about his work or his company; a mother can care about her child, or about her own mother; a nurse can show care to a patient; a community can show caring to someone who has just experienced a disaster or loss. Some elaboration along with an example sentence would help a lot.

Comment: There's an example sentence now, but after reading the comments re Jolenealaska's Empathy answer, I think there needs to be more elaboration or sample sentences, to really nail down what's being asked for. (Empathy, devotion, caring...)

Comment: @A.Beth are you the original asker?

Comment: @catija I am not. The asker is MMM, as noted in the little blue box at the lower right, immediately beneath the query.

Comment: @A I'm aware of how that works... sometimes people create new accounts and then continue to ask questions.  I just don't understand how you can know what the OP meant to ask. Why "fix" a closed question that the OP never came back for?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that "caring" is the word you want.

It can be used as an adjective: "She is a *caring* person."

It can also be used as a noun: "She exhibited a high level of *caring.*"

Answer (score 1):

How about [Empathy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empathy)?

I like that word, and the sense it conveys.

Comment: What I am looking for is effusive caringness, closer to dedication. Any tips? Thanks

Comment: @MMM You mean like how a caretaker or parent might provide for the needs of the one for whom they're caring?